# drag and drag issue with absolute div in table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am creating table dynamically And adding events to it.when i drag and drop events  into table td then event.target.id returns the wrong drop position.it is returning Position where the center position of Div is placed. i need to get td of div top position.

**Note:: Events are Placed with absolute top and Left Position.**

```
dragObj = $('#timesheet td');
$( dragObj ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
       alert('drop'+event.target.id);
      }
    });
```

Comment: could you please provide your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: @VishalPatel dynamically fetching values from db ,div is bigger than row size with absolute top and left  values..

Comment: #SimmiSimmi Sorry, I can't understand...